# StatusDescription with 3g

Tags: android

I have an android project that consumes a REST web service that communicates over 3G or WiFi. When communication is wireless and I get an error occurs with the following error code:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription = new 
CustomException(ex).Error;
```

where `CustomException` is an internal class error handling

but this does not work when it is for 3G